# determining CFL for the complement of a language

Tags: computer-science, automata, context-free-grammar, pushdown-automata

I need to determine whether L is CF
\begin{align}
     \ 
L = \{a^nb^kc^n | n,k≥0\}^c
     \end{align}
I think L can be represented by the following union:
\begin{align}\ 
L=L_1\cup\ L_2
     \end{align}
\begin{align}\ 
\
L_1 = \{a^nb^kc^m | n≠m\} \qquad L_2 = \{w |w∈\Sigma^*\ ,  w≠a^*b^*c^*\}
     \end{align}
I just can't find a CFG for L or disprove it using the pumping lemma...

did I get the complement right?

can I get a general direction, is it a CFL or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If for word $a^n b^k c^m$ we have $n \neq m$, then either $n > m$ or $n < m$.

In case $n > m$ we can rewrite the word as $a^{n - m} a^m b^k c^m$, and similarly for $n < m$ we can write the word as $a^n b^k c^m$.

Let $A$ generate non-empty sequence of $a$ and $C$ generate non-empty sequence of $c$, and $B$ generate (possibly empty) sequence of $b$.

Now, let make $G$ generate words with $n > m$, $L$ with $n < m$ and $E$ with $n = m$.

It's easy to check that rules $G \to AE$, $L \to EC$, $E \to B$, $E \to aEc$ satisfy these conditions. Adding rules $S \to G$, $S \to L$ we get CFG that generates $L_1$.

And $L_2$ is even regular (as a complement to regular language).

Comment: thank you so much!